# How to configure clangd to find missing external header file?

Tags: clang, config, neovim, coc.nvim, clangd

I am a novice user of clang tools and I am learning c/c++.

---

I have some code that is based on a framework that uses its data structure and build system ( [OpenFOAM](https://openfoam.org/)). I compiled the framework's libraries in a folder in home directory. This framework has bunch of directory that keep all the header files of classes as symbolic links in it. I use [neovim](https://neovim.io/) and [coc](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) extention as client, and [clangd](https://clangd.llvm.org/) as language server.

**The problem is, in my code clangd finds some of the header files and not all. What could be the reason for this behavior? and how can I either fix it or get rid of diagnostics in my editor.**

I read the help provided with clangd (`clangd --help`) and turns out there's a flag, `--header-insertion=<string>`, which if I set the `<string>` to `iwyu` (for, Include what You Use), I can get rid of the warnings like this. According to the help, I can configure clangd via a `config.yaml` file in the `~/.config/clangd` folder ([xdg](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-utils/) system in linux). The thing is, how can I edit this file to obtain the effect of aforementioned flag. I simply placed that flag in the file but nothing has changed. Basically what I want is, either config clangd to search for the header files in a directory recursively, Or If that is not possible get rid of the diagnostic warnings of missing header files that it cannot find.

Another thing that I don't know is, how to restart the server to re-read the config. Should I just terminate current process and re-run it?

---

Feel free to edit the question.

Further info:

- OS: artixlinux
- NVIM: v0.5.0-dev+1225-gbbdd00203
- CLANGD: v11.1.0

Comment: Did you resolve it?

Comment: @Rainning kinda. with [bear](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear). `bear -- <build command>`. it will create a hidden config file. `clangd` is able to read that file. unfortunately header files are not detected by `bear`, so you have to add them manually in the config file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said, the project I'm working on does not use CMake as its main build system.

There are (to my knowledge) two ways to fix it.

1. The `bear` utility which generates a `compile_commands.json` file. You have to provide a build command and I believe it will parse the output of that build system to generate the file.

   ```
   # bear -- <build command>

   # In my case
   bear -- wmake
   ```
2. Create a `compile_flags.txt` file at the root of the project, by hand and add all the necessary flags, including paths to directories that contain header files with `-I`

   ```
   -std=c++14
   -m64
   -g
   -IlnInclude
   -I/Volumes/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2206/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude
   -I/Volumes/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2206/src/OSspecific/POSIX/lnInclude
   -fPIC
   -I/opt/homebrew/include
   -I/Volumes/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2206/src/atmosphericModels/lnInclude
   -I/Volumes/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2206/src/fvOptions/lnInclude
   -I/Volumes/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2206/src/renumber/renumberMethods/lnInclude
   -I/Volumes/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2206/src/mesh/extrudeModel/lnInclude
   -I/Volumes/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2206/src/mesh/snappyHexMesh/lnInclude
   -I/Volumes/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2206/src/mesh/blockMesh/lnInclude
   ```
3. Create a local *clangd config file* (`.clangd`) at the root of your project, with the following content (add whatever compiler flags you need):

   ```
   If:
     PathMatch: .*\.cpp

   CompileFlags:
     Add: [-std=c++20, -Wall, -Wextra,  -I/Volumes/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2206/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude]

   ---

   If:
     PathMatch: .*\.c

   CompileFlags:
     Add: [-std=c2x, -Wall, -Wextra,  -I/Volumes/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2206/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude]
   ```

Answer (score 4):

may solution is :
add -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1  to cmake command line
eg : cmake -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1 .

then, it will generate a compile_commands.json file , which could be automatic read by clangd. and i see no more warnings for headers

Comment: What is your project structure? I have `cmake -S . -B out/build` with the `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` set inside CMakeLists.txt. The `compile_commands.json` is generated at `out/build` but my source file is put at `src/` (where this `src` is at the same level as `out`)